# Insert array to sql database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a simple question I have a *string array* (`string[]`) type how can I insert array content to a table in local database.
I already parse the website HTML to shipment_numberArray[], i just need the correct start to insert array content to shptDetails table in NPTSDatabase.

```
string connectionstring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NPTSDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

try
{
    con.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection open !!");

    SqlCommand shptdetailsCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO shptDetails (Waybill) VALUES " +
                "(shipment_numberArray[1])");
    shptdetailsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Is every string a new row in the table or are all strings one single row?

Comment: Could you provide more info, please? What RDBMS (Oracle? MS SQL? etc). What is the table? What is the desired outcome and what is actual result ([please, add your code)

Comment: sorry for not be clear at the first, I have added my code in question, I just need the start hint to insert the array content to table in database, to continue on the right track, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this.

> I am not saying that it would be a good solution according to **performance** and **optimization** but try it and get the idea.

```
namespace InsertingArrayToSqlDatabase
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Table. (tbl_names)
            // ------------
            // | Id | Name|
            // ------------

            string[] names = new string[5] { "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", };

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString goes here.");
            connection.Open();

            for (int index = 0; index < names.Length; index++)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_names VALUES('"+names[index]+"')");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also shouldn't forget to take care about SQL injections:)

Comment: I would optimize it by concattenating the multiple inserts to one string and execute the query just once. Also use using() statements for nicely disposing and closing objects